# learning_curve_dat() with error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, caret, r-s4

So I tried to use the `learning_curve_dat()` function in R to assess model performance but get this error message:

> Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
> Here are some codes:

```
library(caret)

set.seed(2021)
dat <- twoClassSim(1000)

set.seed(42)
learning <- learning_curve_dat(dat = dat, 
                               outcome = "Class",
                               test_prop = 1/4, 
                               method = "svmRadial", 
                               metric = "ROC",
                               trControl = trainControl(classProbs = TRUE, 
                                                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary))
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**Edit**

Additional information: this problem only applies to the svmRadial classification model. The regression model works fine:

```
learning <- learning_curve_dat(dat = dat, 
                               outcome = "Class",
                               test_prop = 1/4, 
                               method = "svmRadial", 
                               trControl = trainControl(method="cv"))
```

Comment: Is  it specific to this `method`.  I tried with `lda` and it worked

Comment: Thank you for replying this post! I found this from [tobigithub](https://github.com/tobigithub/caret-machine-learning/blob/master/caret-parallel/learning-curve-plots-caret-parallel.R) (line 225-240), where the author also has used this function with svmRadial.

Comment: There are some parameters which are passed in that link that is different from yours i.e. `sigma`

Comment: Yes, the accuracy plot works well. So I don't know if the problem was due to```method="svmRadial"```? The error message only showed up when I tried to plot the ROC-curve.